# Wie sagt man "notation" auf Deutsch?

Tags: translation, english-to-german

Ich schreibe gerade eine Arbeit in Deutsch und suche nach einer guten Übersetzung für das englische Wort *notation*. Was ich mit diesem Wort meine, ist sozusagen wie man etwas schreibt. Also welche Symbole ich beim Schreiben benutze.

Ich habe das in mehreren Wörterbüchern nachgeschlagen und habe dadurch die Wörter *Aufzeichnung* und *Darstellungsart* gefunden. Sind diese richtig? Kann mir jemand das besser erläutern?

Comment: _Notation_ ist im Deutschen absolut korrekt. Mir würde da jetzt nichts passenderes einfallen.

Comment: Mehr Kontext wäre hilfreich, aber wahrscheinlich ist „Notation“ am passendsten. http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Notation http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notation

Comment: Since you used upper case for "Notation", I thought that you meant the German word. But this is surely one of those rare cases where two words are reliable friends as opposed to false friends.

Answer (score 7):

Die Frage enthält bereits die Antwort. Wie man etwas schreibt, das nennt man:

```
Schreibweise.
```

Notation ist aber ein weit verbreitetes Fremdwort, das auch gerne benutzt wird. Darstellungsart ist auch richtig. Um zu entscheiden, was besser oder verbreiteter ist, müsste man mehr Kontext haben. Aufzeichnungsart oder -system ohne angefügtes -art oder -system scheint mir falsch. Ein Text als Ganzes kann eine Aufzeichnung sein, aber legt den Fokus nicht auf die Aufzeichnungsweise.

Answer (score 1):

*Notation* passt. In einem mathematischen Kontext schreibt man auch häufig *Bezeichnung.*

> Zum Beispiel:
>
> **Bezeichnung**. Sind *XY* dies und dies, so wird deren ··· mit ··· bezeichnet.

Comment: Nur am Rande: Es mag Leute geben, die das schreiben, aber „die Mathe“ hört sich für mich schrecklich an. Aus der Schule kenne ich „Mathe“ für den Mathematikunterricht („in Mathe“), aber ansonsten ist es „die Mathematik“. Meine persönliche Meinung, ich weiß.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz Danke für den Hinweis. Ich dachte immer, *Mathe* wäre dem englischen Wort *math* ebenbürtig. Gut zu wissen, dass das nicht der Fall ist.

Comment: Womit `in der Mathematik` durchaus richtig ist. Nur mit der verkürzten Form klingt es etwas seltsam.

Comment: @Dawnkeeper, genau das wollte ich sagen, Danke. Ich bin ja froh, das nicht als einziger so zu empfinden.

Comment: Notation im mathematischen Zusammenhang ist in der Tat richtig. Es ist aber nicht dasselbe wie Bezeichnung. Wenn man Buchstaben wie X, Y für mathematische Objekte, z. B. Variablen, Vektorbündel, topologische Räume, verwendet paßt der Begriff Bezeichnung. Aber bei Symbolen wie Integralzeichen, Tensorprodukt oder spezifischen im Kontext definierten Symbolen spricht man besser von Notation, auch bezogen auf die Gesamtheit dieser Symbole.